# Prevent Windows Explorer from instantly waking drive?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

[image: Example interaction]

I have two Explorer windows open. I want to move/copy something from right to left (along the red line in the image). It seems that even dragging at the speed of light Windows decides that it is wise to wake up any drive that I might drag across (like D: in the image).

Is there any way to make Windows delay their waking of drives in this case? This also relates to networks drives that take even longer than normal drives. I'd expect to have to hold over a drive for ~1 second before it actually being an intended target from my drag action.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do what you want, but it seems that your problem would be resolved by simply hiding/minimizing/otherwise shrinking the left panel containing the drives. Treat the left Explorer window as any other when it comes to resizing frames/panels/windows and you should be good to go.