# Dragging large folder past File Explorer (Windows Explorer) 'Navigation' pane can cause FE hang and crash

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there any way to prevent hang when dragging a large file or folder and inadvertently crossing over the `Navigation` pane en route?

Here's a snip I took while it was hanging. I just barely touched `Downloads` (on `C:` SSD drive) while dragging from one location on my `I:` SSD to another on the same drive.

[image: Snip of hanging File Explorer]

My guess is the cause is you're triggering an instant attempt by Windows to start calculating requirements for the move/copy. It's counting files, total size, looking at the destination space available, etc.

So is there any way to put a 300 ms delay on that calculation so that it only happens when the user (me) is actually showing *intent* to move/copy an object there?

Or any other solution? I've tried collapsing the links, but I need them sometimes, so that's not a solution.

In both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, this is a frequent problem for me.

Here's [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/797215/prevent-windows-explorer-from-instantly-waking-drive) from 2014. But in my case, it's not just "waking a drive" - the delay can be minutes.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/821129/how-to-prevent-explorer-exe-to-get-laggy-when-some-network-paths-are-not-availab) is similar, but is about network paths.

Comment: read here https://www.qdoscc.com/blog/windows-explorer-crashes-due-quick-access-view

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I’ve seen that issue mentioned and I’m pretty sure it is a different problem. My ‘downloads’ folder exists. I can drag and drop items into it. But large items take a long time, and, as I’ve described, it seems that Windows begins doing the work to copy/move the files there even if you’re just dragging *past* it on your way to somewhere else.

Comment: 1) Don't drag and drop or show drag contents in options, 2) use "copy to" from Tweak program, UWT or "move to" with rt-mouse.  3) Increase file size in cache 4) use sub-folders better

Comment: I have written many shell extensions for the file explorer.  You might start by asking yourself "what else has been installed into the explorer"?  Although possible, it *probably* isn't a Microsoft bug.  When an action happens in the explorer, every extension is notified (like google drive, etc) and has a chance to eat the processor or crash the parent process (explorer in this case).  I am not blaming this on 3rd party.. but I would certainly start there.  https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I don't have a clean install to test that. I do have Google Drive installed on both machines (8.1, 10), but I don't think it's active on this Windows 10 Machine. Although it's happened many times before, when I tried the same action again a minute ago I was not able to reproduce it. So it seems to be intermittent, which will make it tough to debug in any case.

Comment: You don't need a clean install mr butkus. :)  Just use the tool I pointed out (or even Autoruns can do it).. disable your extensions.. see if it happens.. then add them back one at at time until you find the culprit.  Either way.. this is how to really solve the problem.  It probably doesn't happen without a 3rd party extension or we would ALL be experiencing it.  I also doubt that it is google.. I just point it out because it is another piece of code playing inside of explorer.exe.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It does seem like it's something happening to me, so you're probably right about it being an extension. I will check out your tool. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome Mr. Butkus.  OMG I crack up at your handle.

Comment: One more thing.  If you have any friends that are bada$$es with a debugger, they can look at the call stack when it crashes and tell you which DLL did the naughty.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm glad you appreciate one of my many aliases for use in making dinner reservations or ordering at Starbucks. I've done some debugging in my life, but mostly in Linux. I do wonder if the File Explorer crash would be in the event log. In it, I see an "Application Hang" reported for explorer.exe, saying it "stopped interacting with Windows and was closed." This could be when I stopped waiting and killed the process.

Comment: Do you know the extension tools at www.nirsoft.net ?   ShellExView  get it

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html